# Blackbox-exporter modules header

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, alerting

How to provide headers in modules in blackbox.yml.

```
module:
  prober: http
  http:
    headers:
      Authorization : "----"
```

This returns in error parsing config file:yaml: unmarshal errors

Answer (score 2):

Look's to like a syntax error. This line

```
      Authorization : "----"
```

should be:

```
      Authorization: "----"
```